# Guide.ShowSignIn(1, false) Value not in range exception

Tags: c#-4.0, xna-4.0

In a new Xna game I wroted this:

```
GamerServicesComponent gsc = new GamerServicesComponent(this);
gsc.Initialize();
Components.Add(gsc);

if(!GamerServicesDispatcher.IsInitialized)
    GamerServicesDispatcher.Initialize(Services);
```

And in the Update method

```
 if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
     if (!Guide.IsVisible)
         Guide.ShowSignIn(1, false);  // true doesn't solve it nor 2 or 4 as paneCount
```

I'm receiving a

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Guide.ShowSignIn() can't be used anymore. I Don't know the reason nor if it is really true. But I couldn't get it working with ShowSignIn.

The way I had to login was by pressing the Home button. 
The Guide will appear and you can simply follow the Guide to login.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting a few frames before calling Guide.ShowSignIn() works for me. I don't call it until my game has loaded all assets and at least I frame has been rendered.